# Добавление большого количества вкладок динамически

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Такой вопрос, мне нужно динамически добавить большое количество (180+) вкладок (TabPage) на форму.

Проблема в том, что в какой-то момент (примерно после добавления 53-ой) программа зависает примерно на минуту (иногда появлеятся "Not Responding"), а потом оживает и продолжает работать. Как убрать зависание?

Код:

```
ThreadStart^ threadDelegate = gcnew ThreadStart(this,   &MPT1::Log::DisplayLogFile);
Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread( threadDelegate );
newThread->Start();

void Log::DisplayLogFile()
{
/*....*/
tabControlEntryTabsLog->BeginInvoke(gcnew DrawLogTabsDelegate(this, &MPT1::Log::DrawLogTabs));
}

void Log::DrawLogTabs()
{
 /*...*/
  // adding tabs
  for each (TabPage^ page in tabsArray)
  {
      tabControlEntryTabsLog->Controls->Add(page);
  }
}
```

Comment: 180 вкладок?!111 Вы уверены, что это вам реально нужно?

Comment: @VladD - нужно. Полезные идеи есть?

Comment: Да. Расстрелять вашего UI-дизайнера.

Comment: @VladD - Это самой собой, но переделывать весь дизайн сейчас нет времени, нужно быстро починить....

Comment: Такое впечетление, как будто доходя до определенного количества вкладок, программа увеличивает себе ресурсы и это выглядит как зависание

Comment: А зачем эти пляски с потоками?

Comment: @VladD - вполне вероятно, что UI-дизайнер и топик-стартер - один и тот же человек.

Comment: @Igor: Тем более :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный способ, как было отмечено в комментариях, кардинально переработать UI.

На доли процента можно улучшить ситуацию, временно удалив TabControl с родительского контрола, а вернуть на место после добавления всех TabPage.
Также можно попробовать приостанавливать Layout. То есть:

```
this->Controls->Remove(tabControl1);
tabControl1->SuspendLayout();

for each (TabPage^ page in tabsArray) {
    tabControl1->Controls->Add(page);                
}
tabControl1->ResumeLayout();
this->Controls->Add(tabControl1);
```

Устранить замерзание формы можно костылём, вставив в цикл DoEvents:

```
for each (TabPage^ page in tabsArray) {
    tabControl1->Controls->Add(page);
    Application::DoEvents();
}
```

Но это именно костыль. За него вас могут бить (возможно, ногами).
И это хоть и не даст форме замёрзнуть, но в целом сильно увеличит общее время добавления TabPage.

Вынесение этого цикла в отдельный поток не поможет, потому что регистрация контролов на форме всё равно происходит в её потоке.

Как было отмечено в другом ответе, нужно контент подгружать при выборе элемента. В цикле вставляйте в TabControl **пустые** TabPage. Две сотни пустых контролов вставятся довольно быстро, подвисание формы будет недолгим. А наполняйте каждый TabPage только тогда, когда пользователь переключается на него. Для этого подпишитесь на событие SelectedIndexChanged у табконтрола.

```
Void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
    // Здесь создаём/берём из ресурсов/откуда-то ещё нужные контролы
    Button^ button = gcnew Button();
    button->Text = tabControl1->SelectedIndex.ToString();

    // Добавляем их на выбранную пользователем страницу
    TabPage^ tabPage = tabControl1->SelectedTab;
    tabPage->Controls->Add(button);
}
```

Естественно, самый первый TabPage должен быть наполнен содержимым сразу.

Comment: спасибо большое за советы. По поводу изменения дизайна согласен, но тем не менее интересно решить данную проблему. Я так подозреваю, что зависание происходит в тот момент, когда количество созданных вкладок доходит до какого-то максимального и программа начинает процесс увеличения данного значение (нечто вроде алокации большего количества памяти и копирования существующих вкладок). Так вот, возможно вы знаете есть ли возможность до процесса добавления вкладок на форму узнать это максимальное значение и увеличить его, то есть заранее выделить нужное кол-во памяти?

Comment: Если в [исходниках](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) дотнета проследить цепочку методов добавления контролов в коллекцию, то видно, что вручную установить размер внутренней коллекции нельзя. Даже при вызове AddRange добавление происходит по одному. Разве что использовать неродной TabControl. Но в любом случае никак не избавиться от сложного цикла регистрации компонента на форме. А проблема именно в нём.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делают дерево (или список), а контент подгружают уже при выборе элемента из дерева (списка).